How can I run a Convolutional Neural Network for my latitude and longitude data?
My data differs from what I've seen throughout the internet. I have latitudes and longitudes of an object over time, so a num_time-by-2 data frame. I'd like to use a CNN to model the object's spatial density. I was able to create a matrix with lats as rows, long as columns, and the number of observations at given coordinates as the values, but I'm unsure if this is how Keras would accept the data. The examples I see use images as data.
Furthermore, I have many example datasets. In this example, I have many different objects and a path for each of them. I am using a movement model with three different parameters: velocity, friction, and the variance of the limiting distribution of velocity. My goal is to train my datasets so I can find a relationship between the paths of the objects and the parameter values. Thanks!

I see no inherent problem, either mathematical or programming-wise. CNNs accept outputs that correspond to input matrices, such as images...or whatever other data you stick in the matrix.
The math and the computer do not care if the matrix comes from a photo, a drawing, or density at lat-lon positions. I do wonder if the time component would get lost in your representation as a matrix (no sense of how the object moves through space) and if that would impact performance and if you are using good features in your model, but I defer to your knowledge of the problem.

Thank you.  The time information will be lost like this, but that is where my novelty will come in. Of course, I'll (evidently) need to better my understanding of things :)
